# Never ending Evaluation with Solve. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

Trying to find the equilibrium points for a system of ODE's. However, the code is stuck in running. Any help would be appreciated.

```
f[1] := c n[1] (1 - n[1] - n[2] - n[3]) - e n[1] - (d n[2] + m + p d n[3]) n[1] + (1 - p) c (1 - n[1] - n[2] - n[3]) n[3]
f[2] := p q n[3] (1 - n[1] - n[2] - n[3]) - (e + u) n[2] + q n[2] (1 - n[1] - n[2] - n[3])
f[3] := (d n[2] + m + p d n[3]) n[1] - (e + p u) n[3] 
equil = Simplify[Solve[{f[1] == 0, f[2] == 0, f[3] == 0}, {n[1], n[2], n[3]}]]
```

Comment: Mathematica 12.2 immediately evaluates `{{n[1] -> 0, n[2] -> 0, n[3] -> 0}}`! Restart your Mathematica session

Comment: @UlrichNeumann on V 13.2.1 it seems to not evaluate. I waited also long time for it. On windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

This finishes very fast (from clean kernel)

```
f[1]=c n[1] (1-n[1]-n[2]-n[3])-e n[1]-(d n[2]+m+p d n[3]) n[1]+(1-p) c (1-n[1]-n[2]-n[3]) n[3]
f[2]=p q n[3] (1-n[1]-n[2]-n[3])-(e+u) n[2]+q n[2] (1-n[1]-n[2]-n[3])
f[3]=(d n[2]+m+p d n[3]) n[1]-(e+p u) n[3]
FindInstance[{f[1] == 0, f[2] == 0, f[3] == 0}, {n[1], n[2], n[3]}, Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But if you want to use solve, you could do this and now it finishes very fast.

```
vars=Union[Flatten[Variables[#]&/@{f[1],f[2],f[3]}]]
equil=Solve[{f[1]==0,f[2]==0,f[3]==0},vars,Reals];
```

The solution given for all variables is very long. But deep inside it, you could see same solution given by `FindInstance`

Comment: FindInstance seems to be giving me only the all zero output i.e {n[1] -> 0, n[2] -> 0}

Here is another set of equations that works with Solve
f[1] := c n[1] (1 - n[1] - n[2]) - e n[1] - (m) n[1]
f[2] := (m) n[1] - (u + e) n[2] + q n[2] (1 - n[1] - n[2])
equil = Simplify[Solve[{f[1] == 0, f[2] == 0}, {n[1], n[2]}]]

Output:

{{n[1] -> 0, n[2] -> 0}, {n[1] -> 0, 
  n[2] -> -((e - q + u)/q)}, {n[
    1] -> ((c - e - m) (-((e + m) q) + c (e + u)))/(
   c (-((e + m) q) + c (e + m + u))), 
  n[2] -> ((c - e - m) m)/(-((e + m) q) + c (e + m + u))}}

however FindInstance does not

Comment: **FindInstance does not** the example you posted in your comment works for me using `FindInstance`. Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSdLM.png)   `FindInstance` finds one solution by default. It has option to find more than one instance.

Comment: I tried using the option to find more than one instance. It just pops out an error and only gives the solution of {n[1] -> 0, n[2] -> 0, n[3] -> 0} again. Is there any way to find the other solutions of the equations

Answer (score 0):

In theory successive elimination should work:

```
f[1] = c n[1] (1 - n[1] - n[2] - n[3]) - 
   e n[1] - (d n[2] + m + p d n[3]) n[
     1] + (1 - p) c (1 - n[1] - n[2] - n[3]) n[3];
f[2] = p q n[3] (1 - n[1] - n[2] - n[3]) - (e + u) n[2] + 
   q n[2] (1 - n[1] - n[2] - n[3]);
f[3] = (d n[2] + m + p d n[3]) n[1] - (e + p u) n[3];

s3 = Solve[f[3] == 0, n[3]] // Simplify;
s3 // Length
(*
1
*)

s2 = With[{eqn = f[2] == 0}, Hold@Solve[eqn, n[2]]] /. s3 // 
   ReleaseHold;
s2 = Flatten[
   MapThread[Function[{s20, s30}, Join[#, s30] & /@ s20], {s2, s3}], 
   1];

s2 // Length
s2 // ByteCount
(*
2
26016
*)
```

Up to this point, it took about 30 sec. The rest didn't finish:

```
s1 = With[{eqn = f[1] == 0}, Hold@Solve[eqn, n[1]]] /. s2 // 
   ReleaseHold;
Print["solved"];
s1 = Flatten[
   MapThread[Function[{s10, s20}, Join[#, s20] & /@ s10], {s1, s2}], 
   1];
(* takes longer than an hour to see "solved" *)
```

I don't know how much longer than an hour. This gives some idea of the size of the underlying polynomial system:

```
f[1] /. s2 // Together // Numerator // Map@ByteCount
f[1] /. s2 // Together // Numerator // Map[Exponent[#, n[1]] &]
(*
{680256, 680112}
{7,      7}
*)
```